# Accessing nested attributes in overwritten object using Django

Tags: python, django, object, models

posting this here ; I believe I'll have some trouble figuring it out and it may just save me some time.

In python you can do this :

```
>>> class Toto():
...     def w(self):
...         print(self.name)
...
...
...
>>> class Tata(Toto):
...     name = 'Hehehehe'
...
...
>>>
>>> e = Tata()
>>> e.w()
Hehehehe
>>>
```

Tough, using Django i'm stuck up with this error in the exact same context :

```
object has no attribute 'name'
```

So I tried figuring out if some of my objects didn't had an attribute 'name' but it seems they all have it.

Two questions :

**Any limitation from Django side for this kind of thing ?**

**How can I check which object throws the error so I can check it properly has the attribute ?**

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to figure it out!

So Model overwriting creates a new attribute in the host Class

```
class Base(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        objs = ['Extended'] # name of the overwriting object
        for ob in objs:
            try:
                return getattr(self, ob).name
            except:
                pass
        return 'Unbinded overwritten object'

class Extended(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

Base gets a new attribute called extended. So accessing custom attributes inside required passing through the overwriting object name.

```
> t = Extended(name='test')
> t.save()
> bases = Base.objects.all()
> b[0].Extended.name
'test'
```